# CodeIgniter: Page not found when passing parameters to a controller?

Tags: php, codeigniter, http-status-code-404, codeigniter-url

I'm trying to pass parameters to a control in codeigniter, but I'm getting 404 page not found error, I don't get it, I did what the guide says: http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/controllers.html#passinguri

When I remove the params in the index function and just access the controller everything works fine, but I can't pass a value to it...

Here is the code the way I'm trying to send a param:

> http://mysite/123

```
<?php
class Main extends Controller {

    function index($username) {

        echo $username;

    }

}
?>
```

How can I get more info regarding this error from codeigniter?

Thank you.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

With that URL, CodeIgniter can't understand if you want to pass `123` to the `index` method or if you're requesting the `123` method with no parameters. You have to explicitly name the default method if you need to pass it some parameters.

```
http://mysite/index/123
```

Comment: Is there anyway to bypass it, and make it understand that I'm sending it to index only?  Thank you.

Comment: If you only have the `index` method in that controller, you can set up rewrite via codeigniter's routing; if you have other methods how can you tell if a segment is a method name or an argument for index?

Comment: I'm only passing parameters like this when the controller has only the index function.

Comment: BTW, `http://mysite/index/123` doesn't work either... It needs the name of the controller in the path: `http://mysite/main/index/123`  Why???

Answer (score 5):

Option 1 - Rempap the function call in your controller

If your controller contains a function named _remap(), it will always get called regardless of what your URI contains. It overrides the normal behavior in which the URI determines which function is called, allowing you to define your own function routing rules.
http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/controllers.html#remapping

Option 2 - Use a custom route.

http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/routing.html

Comment: OK, but how do I deal with the fact that codeigniter asks me to specify the controller name as well, like so: http://mysite/main/index/123 `main` is defined as my default controller in the directory, why do I need to specify it?