# How to pass value/variable directly to default controller in codeigniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter

Assume base_url is "http://www.facebook.com"

Default controller is "Home"

How do i code my routes and controller to get my URL as "http://www.facebook.com/noddycha"

Where "noddycha" is a get parameter. The page should load my profile page from DB.

Comment: Assuming Home controller has default `index()` method, let it accept the parameter for your $user_profile.

Comment: possible duplicate of [CodeIgniter: Page not found when passing parameters to a controller?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2751807/codeigniter-page-not-found-when-passing-parameters-to-a-controller)

Answer (score 0):

In your application/routes.php file add this line after `$route['404_override'] = '';`:

```
$route['(:any)'] = 'users/profile';
```

Now absolutely everything will be redirected the `profile` function of the `users` controller (or whichever controller/function combination you substituted in the routes.php file). Then you can get the parameter by doing this in the `profile` function:

```
if ($this->uri->total_segments() === 1) {
    $profile = $this->uri->segment(1);
}
```

If you have some other controllers which you would still like to be able to access, e.g. an about us page, add them after the above line in the routes.php file. For example, if we extend the example above:

```
$route['(:any)'] = 'users/profile';
$route['home/about'] = 'home/about_us';
```

Would mean that every request is sent to the `users/profile` function, except `http://example.com/home/about` will go to the about us page.